# How to pass Unicode correctly to Perl's DBI layer?

Tags: perl, sqlite

I have the following simple Perl wrapper for a Sqlite database:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;

my $sql = shift;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "dbi:SQLite:dbname=data.sqlite3",
    "", # no user
    "", # no pw
    {
        RaiseError => 1,
        sqlite_unicode => 1
    },
) || die $DBI::errstr;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

print Dumper ($sth->fetchall_arrayref({}));

$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

Although I have set `sqlite_unicode` flag, [as explained in the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/DBD-SQLite-1.48/lib/DBD/SQLite.pm#Unicode_handling), I can not execute queries containing Unicode characters:

```
$ ./sqlite.pl "select * from person where lastname = 'Schütte'"
$VAR1 = [];
```

When I mask the 'ü' it seems to work, although I am not sure, if the `\x{fc}` means [Latin 1 `FC` or Unicode `U+00FC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9C#Computing_codes).

```
$ ./sqlite.pl "select * from person where lastname like 'Sch%tte'"
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'id' => 8,
            'firstname' => undef,
            'lastname' => "Sch\x{fc}tte"
          }
        ];
```

When I do the same with the Sqlite command line tool it works fine:

```
$ sqlite3 data.sqlite3 "select * from person where lastname = 'Schütte'"
8||Schütte
```

Did I forget anything to tell the DBI layer to support Unicode characters?

My local encoding is UTF-8:

```
$ locale
LANG=de_DE.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.utf8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.utf8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.utf8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question you need to ask yourself is:

> Should the query be encoded (and if so, in which encoding), or should it be decoded (i.e. Unicode Code Points)?

This should be based on `sqlite_unicode`, but it's not. That only affects returned strings. I suspect that DBD::SQLite, like most/all DBDs, suffer from The Unicode Bug, which means the answer to the question is based on internal details of how the string is stored.

In a UTF-8 system, it usually "just works", and I'm surprised it doesn't here. Please try

```
use Encode qw( decode_utf8 );

my $sql = decode_utf8(shift);
```

If that doesn't work, please provide the output the following (before you shift the query out of `@ARGV`):

```
use Devel::Peek qw( Dump );
Dump($ARGV[0]);
```

---

> *When I mask the 'ü' it seems to work, although I am not sure, if the `\x{fc}` means Latin 1 FC or Unicode `U+00FC`.*

The question doesn't make any sense. In both iso-latin-1 and Unicode, `FC` is "ü". I believe you are actually asking

> Are the returned strings encoded using iso-latin-1, or are they decoded strings (i.e. Unicode Code Points)?

With `sqlite_unicode`, they are the latter. You'll need to encode your output. You can do so as follows:

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

Comment: Doing the explicit `decode_utf8` helps but I have no idea why. What happens during a `decode_utf8` on a system where the locale is set to UTF-8 and where the DBI target also wants UTF-8?

Comment: That's the thing. It's not quite UTF-8 DBI wants

Comment: I spend almost the whole morning reading about obscure Perl Unicode problems. And what I understood so far is, that `decode_utf8` enables Perl's UTF-8 flag. And that is what DBI seems to want. Maybe the reason might be that the default for Perl source code was in the past Latin-1 and most SQL statements are part of the Perl source. And this could be the reason why DBI treats every string as Latin-1. This would make it necessary to turn on the UTF-8 flag to prevent the default. But this are just conjectures. The problem seems to be Sqlite specific. MySQL does not seem to have the problem.

Comment: Decoded strings should be what it excepts. It's actually more complicated than that, but I don't want to go into the details of The Unicode Bug today.